# A problem with a simple command definition

Tags: spacing, macros

I am trying to define a command that writes the word "FACTORING" in sans serif. I did define the command as follows:

> \newcommand{\FACTORING}{\textsf{FACTORING}}

But the when I use the command "FACTORING" does not have any distance to the following letters (see the following small document.) Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}



\makeatletter
\makeatother
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}


\usepackage[style=numeric,firstinits,sorting=none]{biblatex}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{lmodern}    % The Font Type
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\newcommand{\FACTORING}{\textsf{FACTORING}} 



\begin{document}

ssssssssssssssss \FACTORING aaaaaa.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `ss \FACTORING\ aa`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX ignores space(s) after a command name. You can use

```
\FACTORING{} text
% or
\FACTORING\ text
```

to manually reserve or add a space.

Or, you can use the `\xspace` command from [`xspace` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) to automatically add a space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\FACTORING}{\textsf{FACTORING}\xspace} 

\begin{document}
Followed by punctuation: text \FACTORING. 

Followd by inter-word space: text \FACTORING text. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an additional spacing char after your command.
Use: `\newcommand{\FACTORING}{\textsf{FACTORING}\ }` instead

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What if I want to write `\FACTORING` at the end of a sentence: `ss \FACTORING.`? It's better not to hardcode the space in the definition.